# Most innovative business model for companies today

Tags: international-trade, international-economics, multinational-companies

I am not sure if this is the right place to ask questions on this topic, but My class on International business has been asked to present a business plan that will work in the international market, and think of ways to promote it internationally. I am not sure where to start on this. I was looking for some well-established companies to study their business models and proceed with some inspiration from there. We have to primarily focus on the business model with some emphasis on the product too. I would be happy if anyone can guide me to any case study on any innovative business models of our times. Or even point to any such companies. Again, I am not sure If this question is correct for this StackExchange, but I couldn't find any appropriate StackExchange for it so I posted it here.

Answer (score -1):

Start an online international bank that aims to serve the unbanked and that markets itself using prize-linked savings accounts.  If it works out cut me in down the road.